# Adding a record on a crud application

Tags: reactjs

So I have a crud applicatio here this is the link

https://crud-application-x.herokuapp.com/getstudents

my boss was telling me this

Add one record that I can see when I visit the url.

what does it mean by adding a record on a crud app. Does it mean adding new data

Comment: Maybe it would be better to double-check this with them but in my understanding, your boss wants to test whether you're handling data persistence or not.

Comment: So basically testing whether the data works

Comment: I wouldn't say that the data itself, but if you're able to allow users to enter their info and store them somewhere (maybe in a database?), so this info wouldn't get lost when the page is refreshed, for instance.

Comment: @Diego Couto Can you try the link and add the data I wanna know what you notice when you go on the student form tab you can add you data on their and once you click the add student button the data will be saved in a list which is in the get students tab

Comment: You should probably not post a link to an application that is still under development, especially if it deals with student attendance for an university.

Comment: @TobiasTengler Th app is complete the issue is I wanna send it to someone but the problem is the UI is not showing data because it runs on a localhost server

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is not related to a misunderstanding, but that you're both looking at different things. You're probably testing it at your development environment only and everything works as expected. Your boss, on the other hand, is using the app through the URL you've provided and is unable to create a new student.

The issue here is that you are not using the right address to access your API in production, so the student is never created, take a look:

[image]

The address `http://localhost:3200/...` will only work on your development environment. Once axios can't reach the server, adding a new student throws an `Error: Network Error`.

In order to fix this, you'll have to start using the right URL for each environment. The easiest way to do so, in my opinion, is through environment variables.

### How to set up an environment variable

As it looks like you're using `create-react-app`, [this resource](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) will help you set them up as needed. As a simple example, you can create the following two files at your app root directory:

**.env.development**

```sh
REACT_APP_API_PATH=http://localhost:3200
```

**.env.production**

```sh
REACT_APP_API_PATH=https://crud-application-x.herokuapp.com
```

Now you can easily use the right URL for each environment:

```
axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH}/students/addStudent`)
```

Comment: So I need to add custom environment variables do you want me to change the url

Comment: how can I add enviromental variables on the my react app do I have to create a whole new one keep in mind this is a mern stack application

Comment: @AdilAli I've updated my answer with more instructions about how to set up your env. variables. Hope it helps!

Comment: "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd .env.development react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd .env.production react-scripts build",
    "test": "env-cmd .env.development react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

Comment: I changed my script to that and I get get this error when I run my react app  Unable to locate env file at default location (./.env)